# wysiwyg gem's "html_safe" method doesn't work

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, froala

I'm writing a blog and as a form I use `wysiwyg` gem of `froala editor`. Also I have shortened post content on the index page, I use `truncate` method for it. The problem is that `.html_safe` method (that is supposed to display content from the edit form not as `html` code but as plain text) doesn't work in concatenation with `truncate` method. So, here's the code:

**`index.html.erb`**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h3 class="title">
        <%= post.title %>
        <small class="date">
            | <%= post.created_at.strftime('%B, %d, %Y') %>
        </small>
   </h3>
   <p class="fr-view">
       <%= truncate(post.content, length: 100).html_safe %>...
       <%= link_to ' Read more', post %>
   </p>
<% end %>
```

**`_form.html.erb`**

```
<%= form_for @post, role:"form" do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :content %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :content, id:"edit", rows:"3", class:"form-control" %>
    </div>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit 'Create', class:'btn btn-primary' %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#edit').froalaEditor()
  });
</script>
```

that's what returns for the `post.content` in console:

```
Post.find(1)
     <Post id: 1, title: "Lorem Ipsum", content: "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisc..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have inverted the order. `html_safe` marks a string as trusted, but if you then do other operations on it, it's not trusted any more. This should work:

```
<p class="fr-view">
    <%= truncate(post.content, length: 100).html_safe %>
</p>
```

**Update**: After discussing this in the comments, I think the problem is that if you truncate, some tags might remain open, and that might create various problems in your page (not necessarily limited to the content of the string). A couple of options:

1. Do not truncate the string, but limit the displayed portion with CSS; in this case you will still have valid HTML code, which should render properly in the browser;
2. Strip all HTML tags before truncating, like so: `truncate strip_tags(post.content), length: 100`. This will also be more secure as your users could insert malicious code.

As a general note, it is good practice in rails to use [`sanitize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) instead of `html_safe`, to reduce the risk of sending to browsers malicious code entered by a user.

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML code? I don't know froala editor, but the HTML might be encoded; html_safe does not change the string, it just tells rails to trust it.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant. Can you run the console, and post the content of `post.content`. I'm afraid the string might be escaped by froala, in which case you will have to 'unescape' it (with `CGI.unescapeHTML(post.content)`). Might be useful to add what you see and what you expect as well.

Comment: look the question :)

Comment: Sorry didn't see that :) I have read the entire question again: do you want to render the HTML tags (i.e. generate a paragraph when you have a `<p>`), or just strip them out?

Comment: just to display content generated by `froala editor` as plain text, not as `html` code :) the matter is that when I remove `truncate` method it works exactly as I need